# Is there a way in PHP to use null coalesing/nullsafe operators to default to not set any value?

Tags: php, null-coalescing-operator, null-safety

I only see use cases were null coalesing can be used to chain values, but not to omit any value.

Am I missing something essential or is there really no shorthand way to write this:

```
$model->name = "Example";

if(isset($input->name)) {
    $validName = $this->doSomeValidationEventualyReturnNull($input->name);
    if($validName) {
        $model->name = $validName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having a hard time reading the question title but your code could be shortened to $model->name = $this->doSomeValidationEventualyReturnNull($input->name ?? null) ?? "Example";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can propose this one liner, has something to do with null coalescing.

```
$model->name = isset($input->name) ? ($this->doSomeValidationEventualyReturnNull($input->name) ?? $model->name) : $model->name;
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not precise enough: the first line is just to complete the example. I only need a replacement for the nested if-clauses and leave the model untouched if there is no or invalid input.

Comment: OK, I edited the answer, unfortunately I see no way to avoid the double $model->name in the expression.

Comment: this code will cause an error if $input->name is not set

Comment: It's throws a warning - you can prevent this by using `isset($input->name)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although I find it not really easier/more readable than the nested ifs